# Ionic typescript property doesn't exist on HTMLElement type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I use ionic v3 and typescript.

I want to put in array the **file_url** but before I check if his width is equals to his height x 2.

however i have an error:

> The 'name_array' property does not exist on the 'HTMLElement' type.

Here is my code:

```
let img = new Image();

img.src = file_url;

img.onload = function () {

    if( img.width == (img.height * 2) ){
        this.name_array.push({ id: 1, url: file_url });
    }

};
```

How push URL of file in my array ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `arrow` function to access `this` inside the `function`

**According to developer Mozilla docs:**

> Until `arrow` functions, every new function defined its **`own this`** value
>   (a new object in the case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode
>   function calls, the base object if the function is called as an
>   "object method", etc.). This proved to be less than ideal with an
>   `object-oriented` style of programming.

### Arrow functions do not have their own `this`

```
let img = new Image();
img.src = file_url;
img.onload = () => {
   if( img.width == (img.height * 2) ){
     this.name_array.push({ id: 1, url: file_url });
   }
};
```

[**Here is the documentation for the same**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: @Sano, Glad to help you. You can accept and vote my answer, if you find it useful. :-)